# Django changing modelchoice's queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    organizer = models.ForeignKey( Person )
    event_date = models.DateField()
```

I want to create a form for event_id = 1:

```
form_class = modelform_factory( Event, exclude = () )
instance = Event.objects.get( id = 1 )
event_form = form_class( instance = instance )
```

Now, I want to alter the organizer select field so that it only shows the existing person as the only option.  So:

```
event_form.fields[ 'organizer' ].queryset = Person.objects.filter( id = instance.organizer_id )
```

My question is this: in the process of assigning a new queryset, I need to do a new query to the database.  I feel that this is unnecessary as I already have the specific organizer that I want to assign to (`instance.organizer`).   Is there a way to convert this organizer instance into a queryset thereby avoiding the need to do a new query?

It's not a big deal for one form, but I do want to make a formset out of the modelform which would mean *n* queries for *n* forms.  Thanks.

Comment: Or is there another way to alter the options in the select element without using queryset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this below code

```
from django import forms

instance = Event.objects.select_related().get(id=1)
choices = [(instance.organizer.pk, str(instance.organizer))]
event_form.fields[ 'organizer' ] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)
```

Comment: I get `'tuple' object has no attribute 'all'`.  I'm on Django 2.0 running Python 3.5

Comment: That's nifty, but now I am getting `'tuple' object has no attribute '_prefetch_related_lookups'`